# arm asm/neon optimisation for image processing

Tags: ios, uiimage, arm, neon

I m currently working on a painting app on ios.

I use a directly draw into a NSMutableData buffer and apply blending with my brush like this:

```
- (void) combineColorDestination:(unsigned char*) dest source:(unsigned char*) src
{

const unsigned char sra     = ((unsigned char *)src)[3];
const float oneminusalpha   = 1.0f - (sra / 255.f);

int d[4];

for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    d[i] = oneminusalpha * ((unsigned char *)dest)[i] +  ((unsigned char *)src)[i];

    if (d[i]>255)
        d[i] = 255;

    ((unsigned char *)dest)[i] = (unsigned char)d[i];
}

}
```

Any suggestions for optimisations ?

I previously tried to use neon , but i ve got a bug I wasnt able to fix (the bordering pixels was buggy)

I was iterating pixels 2 by 2 like this :

```
uint8x8_t va = vld1_u8(dest);
uint8x8_t vb = vld1_u8(src);
uint8x8_t res = vqadd_u8(va,vb);
vst1_u8(dest, res);
```

Comment: Are you on iOS 4.0, where using the Accelerate framework might be a possibility?

Comment: I am , please provide more details

Comment: Why not use CoreGraphics layers to do the blending for you in hardware? That is going to be faster than your home grown and unoptimized code.

Answer (score 2):

Suggestions? Alright. Note that these are valid whichever multimedia manipulation you are doing and is hardly restricted to your case.

First, before you even do NEON, you should change your code to have one function that changes a bunch of pixels (at least a row, a rectangle if you can) at once, instead of a function (or method - even worse) that changes one pixel and is called a bunch of times: somehow I doubt the brush is only 1x1 pixel.

Second, except for the column loop (and eventual row loop), there should be no branch (that is, flow control structures). No `for (i=0;i<4;i++)`; just write the code for the four channels in sequence (use a macro if necessary). No `if (d[i]>255)`; express that as an alternative: `dest[i] = (temp>255?255:temp);` at the very least, if not replacing it by a more efficient way to do saturation (tricks using subtractions, shifts, and masks exist).

Third, avoid any conversion between floating-point and integer; this is always valid advice, but float->int conversions are particularly devastating on ARM. Since you're manipulating integers, this means foregoing floating-point here.

And once you've done that, surprise, besides making your code faster you have in fact done the preparation work for NEON: NEON is only remotely useful if you process a bunch of pixels at once, if there is no branch, and if you don't convert between floating-point and integer all over the place. So only then will we talk about NEON, if it is even necessary at this point.

Comment: well post was 2 month ago, I made some optimisations #define FASTCOMBINE  temp = (oneminussrcalpha * ((unsigned char *)dest)[i]) +  ((unsigned char *)src)[i]*255;\
temp = temp >> 8;\
temp = (temp>255)?255:temp;\
((unsigned char *)dest)[i] = (unsigned char)temp;\
i++;


static inline void combineColorDestination(unsigned char* dest,unsigned char* src)
{
     
    const unsigned char sra     = ((unsigned char *)src)[3];
    const unsigned char oneminussrcalpha = 255 - sra;
    unsigned int temp;
    unsigned int i = 0;
    
    FASTCOMBINE
    FASTCOMBINE
    FASTCOMBINE
    FASTCOMBINE
    
}